# Nginx: What does 'upstream disconnected' log means?

Tags: ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I tried TLS connection from <10.220.17.192> to the external server(10.220.224.126) via nginx through reverse proxying, but at the external server, the connection is going to TIME_WAIT instead of getting ESTABLISHED.

From the nginx debug logs, I could see, "upstream disconnected".  Does it means the external server closed the connected ?

```
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 event timer del: 4: 82382883
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [info] 10166#0: *11 proxy 10.220.17.192:50125 connected to 10.220.224.126:6515
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 malloc: 08DA8A10:16384
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 post event 08D8EFD0
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 event timer add: 3: 14400000:96778145
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 event timer: 3, old: 96778145, new: 96778145
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 delete posted event 08D8EFD0
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 SSL_read: 0
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 SSL_get_error: 5
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 posix_memalign: 08E22BE0:256 @16
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 write new buf t:0 f:0 00000000, pos 08DA8A10, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 stream write filter: l:1 f:1 s:0
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [info] 10166#0: *11 upstream disconnected, bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to the question after analysing logs from nginx source code.

nginx sends a post event if it receives connection closure from the external server.

```
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 post event 08D8EFD0
```

The manual page for SSL_read says, if SSL_read: 0

*The read operation was not successful. The reason may either be a clean shutdown due to a “close notify” alert sent by the peer (in which case the SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN flag in the ssl shutdown state is set (see SSL_shutdown(3) and SSL_set_shutdown(3)). It is also possible that the peer simply shut down the underlying transport and the shutdown is incomplete. Call SSL_get_error() with the return value to find out whether an error occurred or the connection was shut down cleanly (SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN)*

```
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 SSL_read: 0
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 SSL_get_error: 5
2020/12/10 15:09:51 [debug] 10166#0: *11 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
```

For the below nginx logs , this is what the manual says,

```
2020/12/11 09:13:06 [debug] 11489#0: *1 SSL_shutdown: 1
```

*If the peer already sent the “close notify” alert and it was already processed implicitly inside another function (SSL_read(3)), the SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN flag is set. SSL_shutdown() will send the “close notify” alert, set the SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN flag and will immediately return with 1. Whether SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN is already set can be checked using the SSL_get_shutdown() (see also the SSL_set_shutdown(3) call).*